# Rotate left an Array in C without a for?

Tags: c, for-loop, time, rotation

I'm writing a code and I need to rotate left an array many times. The problem is that I use a `for` loop.

When I need to use the function with a short array it's fast. But as soon as I use an array of 10.000 elements and more it's really long because of the `for` loop.

So I would like to know if there is another way to rotate an array in C which don't need a `for` or `while` (or any other loop)?

```
void rotate_left(int *array, int size)
{
    int nb = array[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    array[size - 1] = nb;
}
```

Comment: This is where you should use a linked list instead of an array. Then it's only a matter of moving one single node from the start to the end of the list.

Comment: The problem with arrays is that they are stored continuously in memory. Therefore shifting/rotating it to the left means touching all elements. This becomes slow for many shift/rotate queries and big sized arrays. As @Lundin has stated: a linked list is much better suited for this task and runs in constant time (if you have access to the head and tail).

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, thanks you !

Comment: This kind of data arrays are generally coded as **circular buffers** (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), where all access can be made very fast by simply updating the head and tail pointers.

Comment: Your rotation way is wrong: `int rot[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
 rotate_left(rot,2);` outputs: `rot[0]:2
rot[1]:1
rot[2]:3
rot[3]:4
rot[4]:5`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to rotate an array in C without a loop?

*No*.

Arrays are stored in continuous memory, so any shifting means linearly accessing its elements.

At least not a clear one. I mean there is the [Circular Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), which uses fixed size buffer, but it's more complicated than an array. For example, when that buffer gets full, you need to overwrite the oldest element with the new one. I think you don't want that.

---

> I'm writing a code and I need to rotate left an array many times.

That shouts for the usage of a simple *linked list*, instead of an array.

In the list case, you would just need to move the node at the start to the end of the list.

If you search the Internet for "rotate left a simple linked list", you will find numerous examples.

Comment: i think there is a way to implement array element rotation, bitwise shifting array elements.

Comment: At the end @EsmaeelE, it would still need to access the elements, while with a list you wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to arrays:

If you double the buffer and copy the array to it's own end you could use

```
void rotate_left(int **array, size_t size, size_t *shiftd){
    if(++*shiftd >= size){
        *shiftd %= size;
        *array -= size;
    }
    ++*array;
}
```

Assuming the `init()` funtion works the same multiple times you could create the array like this:

```
int *array = malloc(2 * size * sizeof(int));
init(array, size);
init(array + size, size);
size_t shiftd = 0;
```

And use the rotation funktion

```
rotate_left(&array, size, &shiftd);
```

This should demonstrate the process of shifting

```
array
 v
[1|2|3|1|2|3]
------- size = 3, shiftd = 0
[1|2|3]

***rotate_left(&array, size, &shiftd);***

  array
   v
[1|2|3|1|2|3]
  ------- size = 3, shiftd = 1
  [2|3|1]

***rotate_left(&array, size, &shiftd);***

    array
     v
[1|2|3|1|2|3]
    ------- size = 3, shiftd = 2
    [3|1|2]

***rotate_left(&array, size, &shiftd);***

array
 v
[1|2|3|1|2|3]
------- size = 3, shiftd = 0
[1|2|3]
```

This however does not work with zero-terminated strings.